# Merge two Json files with awk in bash

Tags: json, linux, bash, ubuntu, awk

I try to merge two json files in a one file, but with one condition, e.g : if the file 1 has for example : testa:result>fail and the file b contains the same line but with a different result e.g : testa:result>pass, i would like that the file 1 it will be update with the results from file 2, i have this line with awk command but it only merge the files without this condition :

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "{"} FNR > 1 && last_file == FILENAME {print line} FNR == 1 {line = ""} FNR==1 && FNR != NR {printf ","} FNR > 1 {line = $0} {last_file = FILENAME} END{print "}"}' json_files/* > json_files/all_merged.json
```

Please I need help with this.

Comment: Please offer more information about input and expected output.

Comment: sorry, here is more information : file1.json contains  the following                       Testname: color  "result": "fail",  and the  file2.json contains the following :  Testname: color "result": "pass",                                                   and i will expected that the file3.json contains the same line with the last result, e.g :                                                                                                Testname: color "result": "pass",                                                                                this because why the file2.json is newer

Comment: Is awk a requirement? Actually it seems a bit awkward :)

Comment: no, could be anything that works in linux :)

Comment: Please post the input and expected output in the question itself, not in a comment. Also, take a look at [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for manipulating JSON instead of using `awk`.

Comment: i dont think that it would be a good idea because the question needs to be clear to the people in general, so if you have a comment that why it must be in that way please feel free adding, and thanks for the recommendation but i think that it would be great if you help me with an example :)

Comment: is the content of these files an array? how is identity defined in what you want to accomplish? Is `Testname` a unique key for the objects in your arrays? it's really not clear what the requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use `python` for the task. Consider this example:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

fileName1 = "file1.json" # file1 contains something like { "Testname": "color", "result": "fail" }
fileName2 = "file2.json" # file2 contains something like { "AnotherTestname": "color2", "result": "pass" }
fileNameTo = "file3.json"

def visualize(data, prompt):
    print(prompt)
    pprint(data)
    raw_input("Press <Enter> to continue: ") # this line pauses the execution

def loadData(fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        return json.load(f)

jd1 = loadData(fileName1)
visualize(jd1, "Data from %s" % fileName1)
jd2 = loadData(fileName2)
visualize(jd2, "Data from %s" % fileName2)
jd3 = jd1.copy() # create a copy of data from file1, this step can be avoided if you don't need unmodified jd1
visualize(jd3, "Data after copying")
jd3.update(jd2) # merge copy of data from file1 with file2, updating corresponding keys
visualize(jd3, "Data after merging")
with open("file3.json", "w") as f3:
    json.dump(jd3, f3)
```

This version of script gained some "interactivity", it let you control data state on each step of execution. I've just checked it performs data merging as expected. Please try to run it against your test data and look at the output.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your script, but i have a little problem, the problem is that the file 1 contains e.g 100 lines and the file 2 contains e.g 50 lines, so after run the python script the file3.json contains the exact lines as the file2.json, and is the same information :( .                                                               so the main idea is that the file1.json always will be updated with the results from file2.json

Comment: #user3159253 can you help me ?